# Volume issue with Bluetooth paired device

Tags: bluetooth

I have an issue with already paired audio devices via Bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04. When a device is reconnected sound is turned to maximum and volume is lower than usual. To fix this issue I have to remove a device and pair it again, then the volume is controlled normally.
Any suggestions on how to fix the issue with the volume?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please add a link to the bug fix or something to prove what you have wrote above.

Comment: Although more information would be helpful, this is the original poster's self-answer, so presumably it is based on having recently tried 20.04 and found it to work.

Comment: I had this volume issue with JBL Clip 3. After updating Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 on my laptop commented issue is not reproducible. I don't know what exactly changed on 20.04 just I wanted to update this post after using Ubuntu 20.04 more than a month.